# Linux: how to block playing videos?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

How can I block playing all possible kinds of videos (.mpeg .avi. flash etc.) by users on Debian Wheezy (with Gnome)?

1. Which packages/plugins should I deinstall (or block somehow)?
2. How can I make sure that users do not run precompiled binaries with players that they might bring on their usb sticks?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do they have internet access on the box, or can they load files off of a USB drive or CD drive?

Comment: @DarthAndroid - no internet access, but USB ports which can be used to attach usb sticks/cdrom/etc.

Comment: Then just keep in mind it would be trivial for a user to bring in a video player unless you keep an eye on what they do with the computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uninstall packages like `vlc` and `mplayer` (start with

```
aptitude search '\<(player|media|movie)\>' | grep '^i'
```

but note that you do not have to uninstall *everything* from that list and the list might miss some packages).

However, if you fear that people will bring executables on their usb sticks (i.e., they have physical access to the box), I am afraid you are in trouble (usually physical access implies an ability to compromise a system).

Still, you can try making the removable media mount in non-executable mode (i.e., no file there is executable) using the `noexec` option to `mount` (or in `/etc/fstab`) and placing user directories on a partition mounted in non-executable mode. This way they will not be able to run the players from there. Note that you will have to make `/tmp` and all the other places writable by the users mounted non-executable too.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anything else except for `/tmp` that I should make `noexec`?

Comment: You need to mount non-executable every directory writable by the user.

Comment: what are they? is there a command to find them all?

Comment: yes, `find` - the man page is long, but it is well worth working through